# Omnifaces LinkageError

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, omnifaces, payara

this is my first post, I hope don't be a mess.

I'm getting the following error when I tried to deploy and **ear** app:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/Document"
```

**I'm using:**

```
Omnifaces 3.4.1
Payara 5.26 (Running on Oracle JDK1.8.0_202)
JEE8
Primefaces 8.0
```

**Full stack trace:**

```
[2022-01-06T12:33:16.769-0500] [Payara 5.26.0] [GRAVE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=175 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1641490396769] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OmniFaces failed to initialize! Report an issue to OmniFaces.
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5758)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1900)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1631)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:108)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:364)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:623)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:654)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:645)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.InstanceDeployCommand.execute(InstanceDeployCommand.java:223)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1879)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:409)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandMultInMultOut(CommandResource.java:258)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:176)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:469)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:391)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:80)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:253)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:356)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OmniFaces failed to initialize! Report an issue to OmniFaces.
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5843)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.callServletContainerInitializers(WebModule.java:738)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5733)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: OmniFaces failed to initialize! Report an issue to OmniFaces.
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ApplicationInitializer.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.callServletContainerInitializers(StandardContext.java:5835)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/glassfish/web/loader/WebappClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/w3c/dom/Document"
    at org.omnifaces.util.Xml.createDocument(Xml.java:66)
    at org.omnifaces.util.Xml.getNodeTextContents(Xml.java:156)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViews.scanAndStoreWelcomeFiles(FacesViews.java:400)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViews.registerForwardingFilter(FacesViews.java:263)
    at org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer.onStartup(ApplicationInitializer.java:54)
    ... 90 more
]]
```

[EAR Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onF8B.png)

[WAR Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21QEG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem removing this property on domain.xml:

```
<system-property name="fish.payara.classloading.delegate" value="true"></system-property>
```